# Why Flutter2.5 icon text field color changes from black to white?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter2.0

- Flutter2.2 shows the **black color** as icon text fields.
- Flutter2.5 shows the **white color** as icon text fields.

After adding `IconThemeData()`, I can see the **black color** as icon text fields in Flutter2.5

```
appBarTheme: xxx(
  iconTheme: IconThemeData()
)
```

So, I had to add this code for the icon text fields.
Which source code has been changed in Flutter2.5?

Thanks for the help.